# how to give live url in ffmpeg for video

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video named video.mp4 than

> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -r 0.25 output_%04d.png

then I got images from that video but in place of that local path can I give a URL for that i.e Link of youtube ?

Comment: You can give a URL if the video is directly accessible at that URL.

Comment: i had given direct url but it shows unknown error